# "reportMissingImports" error even though code and import works fine in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Small question but annoying. In VSCode, it is reporting a "reportMissingImports" error even though the import and the code is working fine. Here is the relevant portion.

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context

...

context = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=":".join(custom_cipher_suite))
```

The line with import create_urllib3_context is being reported as an error but the code runs fine and executes the module as the last line shows. In the python interpreter it runs fine:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context
>>> create_urllib3_context()
<ssl.SSLContext object at 0x7f6c22d2d340>
```

Any idea why this is? I would like to avoid ignoring the error as that will also avoid it for legitimate purposes.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of the program and problem in VS Code:

[image]

Here is the output:

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM
ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM
ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384
RSA-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305
DHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305
ECDHE-PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305
DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM8
DHE-PSK-AES256-CCM
RSA-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384
DHE-PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384
AES256-GCM-SHA384
AES256-CCM8
AES256-CCM
ARIA256-GCM-SHA384
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384
PSK-CHACHA20-POLY1305
PSK-AES256-CCM8
PSK-AES256-CCM
PSK-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM8
DHE-PSK-AES128-CCM
RSA-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256
DHE-PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-GCM-SHA256
AES128-CCM8
AES128-CCM
ARIA128-GCM-SHA256
PSK-AES128-GCM-SHA256
PSK-AES128-CCM8
PSK-AES128-CCM
PSK-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256
AES256-SHA256
CAMELLIA256-SHA256
AES128-SHA256
CAMELLIA128-SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA
SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
RSA-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
DHE-PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384
RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384
DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384
AES256-SHA
CAMELLIA256-SHA
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA384
PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA
PSK-CAMELLIA256-SHA384
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
ECDHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA
SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA
SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
RSA-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
DHE-PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
ECDHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
RSA-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
DHE-PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
AES128-SHA
CAMELLIA128-SHA
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256
PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
PSK-CAMELLIA128-SHA256
```

Answer (score -1):

The python version you use in the command line is *Python 3.10.6*. Select the same python interpreter in vscode(*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> Python: Select Interpreter*) and the version will be displayed in the lower right corner.

[image]

In addition, the way to execute the script should be to use python extension.

[image]

If you want to rudely ignore the error, use the following setting:

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportMissingImports": "none",
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've done both of those suggestions and the same warning occurs. The file runs fine. The problems is that VS Code tells me there's an error when there's not and I would like to fix it without ignoring all "reportMissingImports" warnings.

Comment: Show your execution process and error interface.

Comment: I added a screenshot and the output of the program above. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: How do you execute the script? Does the code run correctly?

Comment: Just a simple `python test.py` from the command line after activating the virtual environment.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Do you know what is the correct way to execute it? Obviously your virtual environment does not have the required package, either install the module for your virtual environment, or switch to an environment with modules and execute the script. The same is true for the terminal. I don't understand why there is any confusion about such a simple question.

Comment: Did you read my question or my replies? The code runs fine. The package is installed. It runs exactly the same as the way you suggested. It just being flagged as an error in VS Code when it's not, and I would like to not disable the error.

Comment: In the reply above, you talk about using the command execution code. Is this the same as the answer? Your expression is so confused.